# Using Excel Formula, add text into a comma separated list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula that builds a connection string. I would like to add text from a column to a comma separated list in another column to the connection string column.

| PORT | DOMAINS | CONNECTION STRING |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 80 | a.domain.com,b.domain.com,c.domain | a.domain.com:80,b.domain.com:80,c.domain:80 |
| 88 | a.domain.com,b.domain.com,c.domain | a.domain.com:88,b.domain.com:88,c.domain:88 |

I've searched google for excel formula to add text into a comma separated list but unable to find a formula that satisfies my criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following formulas:

[image]

---

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,TEXTSPLIT(B2,,",")&":"&A2)
```

---

Or, Using `SUBSTITUTE()` & `TEXTBEFORE()` function:

[image]

```
=TEXTBEFORE(SUBSTITUTE(B2:B3&",",",",":"&A2:A3&","),",",-1)
```

---